# php file working in localhost server but not in cpanel

Tags: php, android, cpanel

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
```

//this is my database

```
 include 'db.php'; 

 $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
```

//inputs

```
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
```

//checking query

```
 $Sql_Query = "select * from user_info where email = '$email' and password   = '$password' and phone = '$phone' ";


 $check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query));

 if(isset($check)){

 echo "Data Matched";
 }
 else{
 echo "Invalid combination of Username or Phone and Password ! Please Try     Again";
 }

 }else{
 echo "Check Again";
 }
```

//closing

```
mysqli_close($con);
```

what is the error, please help me out I'm stuck

Comment: That's the question to you: "what is the error"? Stating "it's not working" is not very descriptive. Please provide some details what exactly is failing, whether you see any log or error messages, what you've tried to fix the error (a good read might be https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: try with error reporting on. ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: what error you are getting from cpanel?

Comment: please specify the error that you getting from cpanel ?

Answer (score 0):

Please set the root path to include.

```
<?php include('db.php'); ?>
```

Your issue may be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is only on server , the following might help you:

1. Check mysqli is enabled on server or not.
2. Recheck username, password and dbname.
3. Check if your db contains a table named user_info if so check column names also.
4. Try debugging using `echo 123;exit;`, and find where the code breaks..
5. Also check error log file.

Hope this helps you.